# conditional statement if all is empty, don't show

Tags: php

```
<ul class="artist-links">
    <?php if(!empty($artist_website)) { ?><li class="artist-website"><a href="<?=$artist_website?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/artist-website.png" alt="<?php the_title(); ?> Website" /></a></li><?php } ?>
    <?php if(!empty($artist_youtube)) { ?><li class="artist-youtube"><a href="http://youtube.com/<?=$artist_youtube?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/artist-youtube.png" alt="<?php the_title(); ?> Youtube" /></a></li><?php } ?>
    <?php if(!empty($artist_twitter)) { ?><li class="artist-twitter"><a href="http://twitter.com/<?=$artist_twitter?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/artist-twitter.png" alt="<?php the_title(); ?> Twitter" /></a></li><?php } ?>
</ul>
```

I want to make this unordered list show up only if at least one of the variables (artist-website, artist-youtube, artist-twitter) isn't empty. So if all of the variables are empty, then this list won't show up at all. What can I add before this code to make this work?

Comment: I have tested the answer below and it works just fine as you would like. Please be sure to accept and vote up the answer if you think that solved your problem. Also let me know if I can be of more assistance.

Comment: The answer you selected as correct is not in fact correct. A better answer is given by Starx below. Mine is correct but Starx gives a more elegant solution.

Comment: Your question was my solution!
+1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check at the beginning if they are all empty:

### Code

```
<?php if(!(empty($artist_website) && empty($artist_youtube) && empty($artist_twitter))) : ?>

<ul class="artist-links">
    <?php if(!empty($artist_website)) { ?><li class="artist-website"><a href="<?=$artist_website?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/artist-website.png" alt="<?php the_title(); ?> Website" /></a></li><?php } ?>
    <?php if(!empty($artist_youtube)) { ?><li class="artist-youtube"><a href="http://youtube.com/<?=$artist_youtube?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/artist-youtube.png" alt="<?php the_title(); ?> Youtube" /></a></li><?php } ?>
    <?php if(!empty($artist_twitter)) { ?><li class="artist-twitter"><a href="http://twitter.com/<?=$artist_twitter?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/artist-twitter.png" alt="<?php the_title(); ?> Twitter" /></a></li><?php } ?>
</ul>

<?php endif; ?>
```

### Explanation

Basically we check each variable for the condition "empty". If all 3 are empty, the result of `AND(true,true,true)` is `true`. Then we see the "!" or the NOT operator, which reverses that `true` and makes it a `false`. So if all the variables are empty, then do no print the lines in between.

You may also notice the ":" / "endif" syntax i've used, which I find much neater when splicing into tags of html.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest changing your design a little bit.

```
//Initialize the variables and define a fixed array for easy manipulation
if($website) { $artist['website'] = $website; }
if($youtube) { $artist['youtube'] = $youtube; }
if($twitter) { $artist['twitter'] = $twitter; }

// If somehow, $artist contains values
if(count($artist)) { ?>
<ul class="artist-links"
   <? foreach($artist as $key=>$value) { ?>
      <li class="artist-<?=$key?>">
         <a href="<?=$value?>" target="_blank">
           <img src="theimage.jpg" />
         </a>
      </li>   
   <? } ?>
<?
}
?>
```

Comment: This is actually a more elegant solution.

Comment: Yeah, and it is useful when the number of artist increase, as in OP's case, it will result in long and ambiguous code

Comment: What to do when the answer marked correct is actually wrong? It has a syntax error. And it doesn't answer the exact question asked.

Comment: Tell him to correct it. Or accept a different correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do exactly what you said above:

> I want to make this unordered list
>   show up only if at least one of the
>   variables (artist-website,
>   artist-youtube, artist-twitter) isn't
>   empty.

Do this

```
<?php 
  if(!empty($artist_website) || !empty($artist_youtube) || !empty($artist_twitter)) {
 //Do what you want to do. Like show the ordered list. 
  } //End of if statement
?>
```

If at least one of the variables has a non empty value the conditional is passed.